# SSIS - Using the SQL Server Schema Name as a Variable for Queries and Procedure Calls

Tags: sql-server, ssis

If this is a duplicate question, then please just point me in the right direction.

My employer has asked me to substitute SSIS for a number of custom SQL Server procedures.  The setup is for development and pre-production to be on one SQL Server database separated by the schema name and then production will be a second SQL server database with a separate schema of its own.

```
DBName              Schema
---------------     -------
OperationsTrials    Sandbox
OperationsTrials    PreProd
OperationsProd      Prod
```

This means within SSIS, all calls to tables, stored procedures etc will need to have the schema name passed in as a variable somehow.  Is this possible and how would one do that?

For example: I created a project variable called "SchemaName" and assigned it the value "Sandbox". Then created a lookup within a package and tried something like the following:

```
" SELECT DateKey, Date from ''' + @[$Project::SchemaName] + '''.Dim_Date"
```

SSIS considers this to be a call to a procedure, (when clearly its not) and therefore fails.

```
" SELECT DateKey, Date from " + @[$Project::SchemaName] + ".Dim_Date"
```

also fails due to a syntax error at the "+" sign.

SSIS will be doing all DDL and DML within the SQL Server 2012+ environment with Visual Studio 2017 and SSDT 2017.

My SSIS skills are marginal still, so any detailed suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your approach is sound. Your second command is a valid SSIS Expression. Where exactly are you putting it? Have you created a variable of type String to put this expression in? I'm working on a detailed answer.

Comment: I agree with @JeremyJ. `"SELECT DateKey, Date from " + @[$Project::SchemaName] + ".Dim_Date"` is a valid SSIS Expression. What is the datatype `@[$Project::SchemaName]` and what is the datatype of the variable the expression is part of?

Comment: The project parameter is of type String with the value of "Sandbox".  The select statement is being used in a Lookup Transformation in the box "Use Results of SQL Query."  I thought that would be an "easy" place to start.  Those are the only declarations I have.

Comment: I wonder if you might need to put brackets around `Date` since it is a reserved word?

Comment: @TabAlleman  - I had tried removing the date field in the query and ran into the same error messages.  But that is an excellent point I should remember for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a great approach. Create a Project Parameter called SchemaName and put a value in. After this is deployed, you can pass in the schema name via environment variables or by overriding values in the SQL Agent job, but I'm not going to cover that in this answer. You seem to be on the right track for your source query.

Create a variable of type String. Paste the expression your wrote in the expression builder, and evaluate it to make sure it works. Then click OK.
[image: Expression Builder]

Create a data flow task, and in the task add a data source. In this screenshot, I am using an OLE DB Data Source. Choose a connection manager. For Data access mode, choose "SQL command from variable" and then select the variable that contains the source query you just created.

[image: data source editor]

At this point add your columns and build your data flow like normal.

Comment: Okaaay - I thought it was simply a matter of defining a variable, in this case [$Project::SchemaName] and plugging it in where ever I needed it.  But it appears that the correct answer is more general than that.  Its the expressions that drive the behavior I need, not the variable itself.