# Need help storing a table's schema in a variable in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I'm making an SSIS solution to store students' marks in a data warehouse. The OLTP database has different schemas to separate the campuses. Both the OLTP and data warehouse has a "Marks" table, but the data warehouse has an additional CampusID column that is a foreign key that references a table called "Campus" that stores a list of the college's campuses. I'm looking for a way to store a table's schema name in a variable, evaluate it to decide what the CampusID must be, and insert that CampusID in the "Marks" table. E.g if the OLTP table's schema is "AucklandPark", the CampusID is 1 and that gets inserted into the "Marks" table.

This is for a project we have to do. I found this solution [SSIS - Using the SQL Server Schema Name as a Variable for Queries and Procedure Calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53009773/ssis-using-the-sql-server-schema-name-as-a-variable-for-queries-and-procedure), but it's not dynamic; the project variable in the solution has a fixed value and I'd have to create fifteen different packages to get the desired result.

The definition for the "Marks" table in the OLTP database looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE AucklandPark.Marks(
    MarkID  INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    StudentID   INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES AucklandPark.StudentInfo(StudentID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FA_1        TINYINT CHECK(FA_1 BETWEEN 0 AND 100),
    FA_2        TINYINT CHECK(FA_2 BETWEEN 0 AND 100),
    FA_3        TINYINT CHECK(FA_3 BETWEEN 0 AND 100),
    SA_1        TINYINT CHECK(SA_1 BETWEEN 0 AND 100),
    SA_2        TINYINT CHECK(SA_2 BETWEEN 0 AND 100),
    INT_1       TINYINT CHECK(INT_1 BETWEEN 0 AND 100),
    INT_2       TINYINT CHECK(INT_2 BETWEEN 0 AND 100),
    INT_3       TINYINT CHECK(INT_3 BETWEEN 0 AND 100)
);
GO
```

And the definition for the data warehouse looks like this (using script generation):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Marks](
    [DW_MarkID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MarkID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DW_StudentID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CourseID] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [CampusID] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [DW_FacilitatorID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DateID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FA_1] [tinyint] NULL,
    [FA_2] [tinyint] NULL,
    [FA_3] [tinyint] NULL,
    [SA_1] [tinyint] NULL,
    [SA_2] [tinyint] NULL,
    [INT_1] [tinyint] NULL,
    [INT_2] [tinyint] NULL,
    [INT_3] [tinyint] NULL,
```

(I'm leaving out all the constraints it adds afterwards)

Comment: This honestly sounds like a design flaw. The schema shouldn't be holding a piece of information (the name of the campus); that should be a a column in your table(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding a column for CampusID.

Comment: That doesn't have anyhing to do with making a schema dynmic in an SSIS package  but I'm glad you solved your problem

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I asked our facilitator about it and he said that making a schema dynamic in an SSIS package was too complex for the purposes of the project, and that having a separate table with all the campuses would be easier.